# C# Webdriver click button which command is selectFrame

Tags: c#, command, webdriver, target

How can I presss a button which command and target (recorded in Webdtriver IDE from Mozilla) are:
command: selectFrame
target: ifr

using C# (not java) in Webdriver, I try this but does not work:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ifr")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need first to switch to the frame:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("YourFrameName");
```

After that the FindElement will search the HTML located in the frame.

Comment: How the code will be then? if in Webdriver IDE from Mozilla says that the target is "ifr" it means your line will say this?                
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("ifr");
and then to click in the button i must put this?
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ifr")).Click();

Comment: I never worked with target and selectFrame, is there any tutorial or web in C# please? I do notyt understand well how I must make the 1 and the 2 line top click in the button which target is ifr using the comand selectFrame...

Comment: You can find full code example in my article about facade pattern- http://automatetheplanet.com/facade-design-pattern/ and find full C# webdriver tutorial here: http://automatetheplanet.com/getting-started-webdriver-c-10-minutes/

Comment: thanks, but I mean how to find the frame in the html? Only because the target is a "ifr" it means it is a frame?

Comment: use the developer tools of Chrome (F12) and use ctrl + f and type "frame" and you should find the frame tags, your part of the HTML should be placed somewhere inside. :)

Comment: thanks, I have no frame in the html, then.. to click in that button I don't know what I have to do, i only know thta when I press that button I recorded it (in webdriver IDE in Mozilla) and appear "command: selectframe" and "target: ifr"

Comment: I think that the name of your is "ifr" if you give view source of the entire page and search inside for "ifr" what happens?

Comment: thanks for all and specially for the links of that web you send me